# How to repeat content of selected cell or cells?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I copy (repeat) selectedCellsValue - till end of row.

Number of cells (i.e. Columns) in a row - varies (about 30).

Excel have that option named - autoFill - Copy.

Here is my try:

```
int x = dgv.SelectedCells.Count;

foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgv.CurrentRow.Cells)
{
    if (c.Selected == true)
    {
        string a = c.Value.ToString();

         x = x+1;

         dgvRasp.CurrentRow.Cells[x].Value = a;
    }
}
```

But it copies selectedCells only once.

Comment: How are you filling the datagrid? You can set a static field in the dataset to the value that you want to show and the grid will show it

Comment: dgv is unbounded (populated by StreamReader - reading a csv file).

loop - ??

Number of selected cells varies.

Position of selected cells varies also.

Comment: Can you provide an example or two of what you want to do? It isn't entirely clear right now.

Comment: David, go to excel, select some nonempty cells and you will have a small indications bottomright. If you drag that indications, you will have options for copy that cells. I want the same - to copy selected cells -  by buttonClick.

Comment: When you say "But it copies selectedCells only once." are you saying that it copies across one column in all the required rows, or are you saying it copies one row across one column? So right now what happens if you have columns A->F and rows 1->5, and you have data in ABC/123 and try to replicate the data across all the way across to F5? Thanks

Comment: Why do you skip first dgv.SelectedCells.Count cells in target grid? You need an outer loop which is terminated when `dgvRasp.CurrentRow` has no cells left to fill, and an indicator which cell is to be copied in case you have selected few cells and want to replicate them in the same order to dgvRasp.

Answer (score 0):

This has some obvious problems if, for example, cells from more than one column are selected for a given row, but it should at least give you something to build on:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in selectedCell.OwningRow.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ColumnIndex > selectedCell.ColumnIndex)
            cell.Value = selectedCell.Value;
    }
}
```